# Image is going out of table in fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

My idea is to print my report to PDF. I have used FPDF to achieve this!

Everything was fine until I was trying to display the image in the table !

The image is going out of the table! it's coming at the top of the row! please check this image

[image: PDFimage]

I have used FPDF **Table with Multicells** 
[Linkoffdf](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3)

And my output page code is

```
require('newtabledata.php');
$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
//Table with 20 rows and 4 columns
$pdf->SetWidths(array(30,20,30,40,60));
srand(microtime()*1000000);
while($at = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 //fetching datafrom database
 $pdf->Row(array($client_final_name,$user_name,$tasstatkname,'Reviewimage'.$pdf->Image('02.png'),$w_note));
}

$pdf->Output();
```

Note:I thought because of image size, I have added 10X10 image as well.

I am not sure where I am wrong ! Did I missing something here?

expected result

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Please show you expected result

Comment: @SAVe please check I have updated my question! give an image to show the expected result !